# Using prepareForSegue for table view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view controller. I have to set a value inside this controller. But I guess above code works only for view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier! == "changeName" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NameSettingTableViewController {
            println("ok")
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't print "ok" to debug. I think because `NameSettingTableViewController` is not a view controller. `destination` variable is returning nil. How can I fix this ?

Storyboard:http://prntscr.com/79846c

Comment: I tried now with debugger and destination variable is returning nil.

Comment: Are you checking `destination`, or are you checking `segue.destinationViewController`?

Comment: I am checking the destination.

Comment: Post your storyboard please

Comment: @Bannings How can I post it ? With a screenshot ?

Comment: So your segue is pointing to the navigation view controller?

Comment: basically what error is  you should try putting identifier in navigation controller and try the same stuff...

Comment: I can't put identifier to navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the navigation controller first, then access its topViewController property to get a reference to your NameSettingTableViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier! == "changeName" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            let destVC = destination.topViewController as! NameSettingTableViewController
            // set whatever variables on destVC
            println("ok")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah this is true...however i missed saying put an identifier and repeat the same thing